# ocamlopt override default arguments passed to linker

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to build a simple ocaml executable with a native function.

Here's the ocaml code `minimal.ml` ... it defines an external function that takes two ints and returns an int.

```
external add: int -> int -> int = "add";;

Printf.printf "%d\n" (add 4 7);;
```

And here's the c code `minimal.c`

```
#define CAML_NAME_SPACE
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>

CAMLprim value
add(value x, value y)
{
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int z;

    x1 = Int_val(x);
    y1 = Int_val(y);

    z = x1 + y1;
    return Val_int(z);
}
```

`ocamlopt minimal.ml minimal.c` generates linker errors but in a really
surpriging way. It is complaining about symbols that seem to be part of the OCaml native runtime, and not complaining about `_add`.

How do I tell `ocamlopt` what arguments to supply to the linker?

```
$ ocamlopt minimal.ml minimal.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_camlMinimal", referenced from:
      _caml_globals in camlstartupf80fc9.o
  "_camlMinimal__code_begin", referenced from:
      _caml_code_segments in camlstartupf80fc9.o
  "_camlMinimal__code_end", referenced from:
      _caml_code_segments in camlstartupf80fc9.o
  "_camlMinimal__data_begin", referenced from:
      _caml_data_segments in camlstartupf80fc9.o
  "_camlMinimal__data_end", referenced from:
      _caml_data_segments in camlstartupf80fc9.o
  "_camlMinimal__entry", referenced from:
      .L115 in camlstartupf80fc9.o
  "_camlMinimal__frametable", referenced from:
      _caml_frametable in camlstartupf80fc9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
Exit 2
```

Comment: There is nothing like a "C linker".

Comment: @Olaf fixed. The OCaml compiler documentation mentions linking in the context of pure-ocaml programs and in those cases I think ld/gold aren't involved ... What's the proper description for the type of thing that ld and gold are?

Comment: What's wrong about "linker"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that both minimal.c and minimal.ml create a file named minimal.o. One fix for this is to rename minimal.c to add.c.

```
$ mv minimal.c add.c
$ ocamlopt -o minimal add.c minimal.ml
$ ./minimal
11
```

**Update**

ocamlopt creates 2 or 3 object files. If you compile a .ml file with no separate interface (.mli) file, it creates .cmi (the compiled interface), .o (the native code), and .cmx (the extra OCaml metadata).

```
$ ls -1
add.c
minimal.ml
$ ocamlopt -c minimal.ml
$ ls -1
add.c
minimal.cmi
minimal.cmx
minimal.ml
minimal.o
```

Comment: Why is `ocamlopt` creating a `minimal.o` for `minimal.ml` instead of a `minimal.cmo`?

Comment: Actually it always creates both .o and .cmx. The .o file has the native code. The .cmx file has the extra OCaml metadata. .cmo files are created by the bytecode compiler.